# Derive public key hash from bech32 address using python

Tags: cardano-serialization-lib, address, python

I know that this is possible in javascript using the cardano serialization lib, as follows:

```
function toHex(bytes){
    return Buffer.from(bytes).toString("hex");
}

function addrToPubKeyHash(bech32Addr) {
  const pkh = Loader.Cardano.BaseAddress.from_address(
    Loader.Cardano.Address.from_bech32(bech32Addr)
  )
    .payment_cred()
    .to_keyhash();

  return toHex(pkh.to_bytes());
}
```

How would I do the same in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [pycardano](https://github.com/cffls/pycardano).
Class `Address` has a class method `from_primitive` that can read and decode a bech32 address. Then you can directly read field `payment_part`, which is the public key hash of the payment credential from the address object. You can find the API documentation [here](https://pycardano.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/pycardano.address.html#pycardano.address.Address).

Example:

```
>>> from pycardano import Address   
>>> addr = Address.from_primitive("addr_test1vzv89dr7v69enywx0t7sqcyxshcmnlv9q43lhpg7ecfhjjsjcdsza")
>>> addr.payment_part
VerificationKeyHash(hex='9872b47e668b9991c67afd00608685f1b9fd850563fb851ece13794a')
```